# Php Post Facebook Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: php, facebook, post, sdk

Evening saw this issue was mentioned and double support multiple Okay, maybe this is something easy for many people, but I'm having trouble with, and keep getting this error repeatedly.

I think the problem in part: App Review. publish_actions but I do not know what to do for it to be accepted. Full declared then.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Review, most permissions only work for users with a role in the App. Try with your App Admin and it should work. Make sure you add the permissions you need in the "scope" parameter, and read about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Here´s an example of a login flow with the JavaScript SDK, take a look at the "scope" parameter: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I did it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

while creating the app in facebook we app an appid and app key give that and in setting add publish action in permissions.